# ¿Por qué obtengo NAN como resultado al restar dos numeros?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

En los **hooks** guardo los numeros con formato **peso Argentino**,
cuando quiero hacer una operacion de resta con esos numeros
como resultado obtengo **NAN**.

```js
const Home = () => {
 const [incomeAmount, setIncomeAmount] = React.useState(0);
 const [expensesAmount, setExpensesAmount] = React.useState(0);
    
 const settingValues = () => {
   setIncomeAmount(currencyFormat(188700));
   setExpensesAmount(currencyFormat(15000));
  
 }
    
 const currencyFormat = (num) => {
   return Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR',{style:'currency',currency:'ARS'}).format(num);
 }
    
  restar = () => {
    const result1 = incomeAmount - 800;
    const result2 = expensesAmount - 800;
    setIncomeAmount(result1);
    setExpensesAmount(result2); 
   }
    
 return (
 <div>
  <p>{incomeAmount}</p>
    <p>{expensesAmountAmount}</p>
 </div> 
 );

}
```

Comment: Pues no tengo ni idea de reactjs, pero apostaría algo a que una vez le das **formato** deja de ser un número (será un string, o un objeto). Los números no tienen "formato", aunque sus representaciones si pueden tenerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te explicaron en los comentarios, si le estás dando formato con el `currencyFormat()` antes de hacer la resta, entonces **deja de ser un entero** y se transforma en un string. Así pues, intentar restarle un número a un string no es posible.

Acá te presento una posible solución a lo que estás tratando de hacer, reescribiendo todo tu código y corrigiendo algunos errores de sintaxis:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Home = () => {
    const [incomeAmount, setIncomeAmount] = useState(0);
    const [expensesAmount, setExpensesAmount] = useState(0);

    // const settingValues = () => {
    //  setIncomeAmount(currencyFormat(188700));
    //  setExpensesAmount(currencyFormat(15000));
    // }

    const currencyFormat = (num) => {
        return Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR',{style:'currency',currency:'ARS'}).format(num);
    }
    
    const restar = (newIncomeAmount, newExpensesAmount ) => {
        const result1 = newIncomeAmount - 800;
        const result2 = newExpensesAmount - 800;
        console.log(typeof(currencyFormat(result1)))
        setIncomeAmount(currencyFormat(result1));
        setExpensesAmount(currencyFormat(result2)); 
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        restar(188700, 15000)
    }, []);

    return (
    <div>
        <p>{incomeAmount}</p>
        <p>{expensesAmount}</p>
    </div> 
    );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Home />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Como se puede ver ahí, mediante `useEffect()`, en el primer render mando a llamar a la función `restar()` con los valores que quiero restar.

Luego les resto el `-800` y recién ahí a los resultados les doy formato con el `currencyFormat()`.

Al mismo tiempo traslado esos resultados a sus respectivos estados y por último los muestro en pantalla.

Haciendo todo eso, la función `settingValues()` no sería necesaria.

Ejecuta el código, mira el resultado y fíjate si es eso lo que buscabas lograr.

PD: Para confirmar que se tranforma en un **string** al darle a los números formato con el `currencyFormat()`, fijate que hago un `console.log()` con un `typeof()` del resultado de esa función. Ese `typeof()` nos muestra por consola que claramente es un **string**.

Comment: Parece ser la respuesta correcta.